How does a separating membrane change the ionic potential in an electrolyte?
I have an electrolyte solution in a closed volume. I separate the volume into two segments by two infinitely thin membranes (i.e., the segments are mechanically separated, but electrically not. Actually, it is one isolating membrane with two surfaces, that is, no electrolyte with movable charge carriers between). The two segments have the same bulk potentials and gradients. I guess that no observable change happens: no more mass and charge exchange, but the two segments have the same macroscopic and microscopic parameters.
Now, I separate the two membranes by a distance $d$ (use a more or less physical membrane). How will the potential and concentration gradients change near the membrane? I mean that when the separation is infinitely thin, the ion repulsion from the left is the same as from the right, so no force changes the potential and concentration near the membrane. However, if the ions on the right side are on the other side of the separator membrane, they are, on average, at a distance $d$ farther than the ions on the left side. That means that the forces get unbalanced, and, in some thin layers, the ions feel more repulsion from the left side than from the right side; that is, the concentration must change near the membrane on both sides.
The effect is evidently significant only where the distance $d$ is in the order where the electric repulsion force is not too small.
The layer with a changed concentration will screen the effect for the bulk on both sides. The concentration change for the bulk is not significant, but surely not so for the layer in proximity to the membrane. According to the Nernst-Planck equation, it also means a potential change. I mean, the thickness of the membrane is nearly in the order of atomic size (that is, the repulsion force changes considerably), so I guess that in a layer of thickness in the order of atomic size, a measurable potential gradient shall be created.
I guess that I can set up a "line charge" with a break of distance $d$, and integrate a $1/x^2$-like potential from minus infinity to, well, not quite zero, and do the same from not quite zero to plus infinity, for distances increased by $d$. How much this idea is fair? (actually, I would like to derive the dependence of the potential in the function of distance from the membrane surface, using $d$ as a parameter. I guess that the gradient is zero inside the membrane, at $d=0$ as well as at $d \gg \text{atomic size}$. But, how does it behave between?)  Is this question discussed somewhere?
A possible reply:
We can assume that having quasi-continuous charge distribution on the two sides of the membrane, an ion at position $x$ experiences a force
$$\zeta_{k} \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}V_{m}(x)$$
from neighbors in one direction, which force is counterbalanced by a similar force from the other side. When we separate the two segments by distance 1 (we measure distance in units of the thickness $d$), the second force reduces and a net force is
$$F_{e}=\zeta_{k}*\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}V_{m}(x)-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}V_{m}(x+1)\right).$$
Given that the potential is composed of the potential of individual ions of form $\dfrac{1}{x^{2}}$, we assume that
$$F_{e}\propto \left(\int_{0}^{-\infty}\frac{V}{x}-\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{V}{x+1}\right)=-F_{e}\left(\bigg[\ln(x)\bigg]_{0}^{\infty}+\bigg[\ln(x+1)\bigg]_{0}^{\infty}\right).$$
We use the approximation that $\ln(\infty)\approxeq \ln(1+\infty)$ and arrive at the voltage gradient due to placing a separator membrane in the volume
$$\frac{V_{m}}{\mathrm{d}t}(x)\propto V \ln \left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right).$$
The result is shown below. There is a gap (no electric carrier inside the membrane), and the potential remains the same in the bulk. However, it steeply increases on the two layers near the boundary surfaces of the membrane, although the layer is very thin. (Of course, the membrane surfaces are ideally flat, and the ions are finite-size balls, so the distance from the membrane, and similarly, the layer thickness, does not decrease infinitely.)
From this point on, we can use the Nernst-Planck equation: the potential means at the same time the presence of ions in the layer; i.e., it causes a concentration change, and the concentration gradient modifies the potential.
Anyhow, the effect works in a way that no concentration or potential difference is between the segments, and still, a potential difference exists.
The result matches my expectations. Is there something against its idea, result, conclusion or mathematical derivation?

